# Python Anaconda reinstall

Tags: python, deep-learning, anaconda

I had a working deep learning library on CPU Linux Mint ubuntu verion 18.3 with Anaconda 3.6 but something got hosed when I was tinkering around in Theano.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/setup-python-environment-machine-learning-deep-learning-anaconda/

Everything was working just fine until I wanted to tinker around with a few .py files with `KERAS_BACKEND=theano python program.py` and in an attempt to fix something not working in Theano, I did this command from the theano website

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano_versions/dev/requirements.html

`conda install numpy scipy mkl <nose> <sphinx> <pydot-ng>`

Not knowing what I am doing it almost seemed to pooch everything... And install Python 2.7 dependencies. Would anyone be able to give me a tip on how reset my deep learning library in anaconda 3.6 build???

If I do a `conda list anaconda$` its a custom build 2.7 which was not intentional! Time to start learning how to do virtual sessions :)

Comment: 1) Please do not post terminal output in an image. See here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481 2) What about `conda install anaconda python=3`?

Comment: Can anyone give me a tip on how to remove the 2.7 environment? I downloaded the conda cheat sheet, and I am attempting to use `conda env remove --name bio-env` but how do I specify environment 2.7?

Comment: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/cheatsheet.html

Comment: `source activate py36` worked to get 3.6 environment back but how do I make that the default and completely remove 2.7?

Answer (score 21):

1. Read the docs for uninstalling Anaconda
   https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall
2. Do a `conda install anaconda-clean`
3. Then a `anaconda-clean --yes`
4. Then re-download the Anaconda 5.2 For Linux Installer and run thru
   the steps. https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem and just did:

```
conda install --revision 0
```

this gives me a fresh Anaconda installation, with the drawback of needing to install every package again. Hovewer, all environments created remain intact.

More on Anaconda revisions here: https://medium.com/@wilpat456/fix-broken-anaconda-environment-due-to-recent-package-download-9094fb0f3a04